# How do i place these 2 buttons in different forms, side by side

Tags: html, css

I have a login and register button both in different forms since the login input will use a post method while the register input will use a get method. Current outcome is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1LqT.jpg

I just cant seem to find a way to float the 2 buttons beside eachother without changing the current layout of the forms, I want it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ching.jpg

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div align="center" class="half">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" action="login">
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username"> 
      <br>
      <br>
      Password:
      <input type="password" name="password">
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdaVHYUAAAAAIxBlaPMTaE0Cuwhb5SK5Q10JKt1"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <form action="login" >
      <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="./recover.html">Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.half{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the [`align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Attribute_list) property is not for `div` elements.

Comment: If you don't want to pass username and password to the target page, the requested layout does not looks good.

Comment: You do understand the second form does not contain the name and password fields, nor the captcha, right? By default, it sends an empty form. You'd need JavaScript to collect the data and send it. If you're going there, you're better off using only one form and deciding where it's sent based on this custom logic.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i have java to handle both forms, the register form is not supposed to send anything, my java code just redirects it to my register.jsp page.

Comment: I still can't see any benefit whatsoever from having the second `<form>`. Since you're always relying on getting the info from first form, why not use the same form and decide what you do with the data on server side, based on the value of a particular field value (`isRegister` or sorts)?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu well the action="login" is part of my java servlet which takes in POST and GET methods and returns different outcomes for both methods. The first form does a POST method while the second does a GET method, and I cant have both varaiations in the same form that is why i did it this way. 

Here's a look at my java servlet:
 protected void doGet() {
  response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
 }
 protected void doPost(){
  ServletUtility.login(request, response);

Comment: I don't actually need the details. It's an uncommon pattern and chances were you were using it other than it was designed for, leading to more problems. If you know what you're doing, happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved your code to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d0ugac8n/

If you only have the Button in the login form, you can do the following:

```
form[action*="login"] {
    display: contents;
}
```

This basically means "ignore the form itself and only show the child elements".

**Word of warning** `display: contents` is currently not hugely supported (IE, Edge of course). If you need better browser support, you can achieve something similar with

```
form[action*="login"] {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be very nasty, when you do not want to change your layout, but you can position the other form like this:

```css
form + form {
  display: inline-block;
  transform:translate(100%,-100%);
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="half">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="login">
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username"> <br><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdaVHYUAAAAAIxBlaPMTaE0Cuwhb5SK5Q10JKt1"></div>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <form action="login" >
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
<br>
<a href="./recover.html">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps! It's a fairly hacky way and I noticed upon zooming in the "Forgot Password" slowly moves off-center. I can play with it more if you'd like help trying to maintain it's position, otherwise, good luck :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center" class="half">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="login">
Username:
<input type="text" name="username"> <br><br>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdaVHYUAAAAAIxBlaPMTaE0Cuwhb5SK5Q10JKt1"></div>
<br><input class="logreg" id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<form action="login" >
<input class="logreg" id="register" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<br><br>
<a href="./recover.html">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.half{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logreg
{
    float: left;
}

#login
{
    margin-left: 46%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

a
{
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the other form and put the Register button inside the other form and add `display: inline block` class or something to the both buttons.

Here is the code:

```css
.half {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div align="center" class="half">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" action="login">
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username"> <br><br> Password:
      <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdaVHYUAAAAAIxBlaPMTaE0Cuwhb5SK5Q10JKt1"></div>
      <br><input type="submit" value="Login">
      <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="./recover.html">Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I cannot add the register button to the other form, because it will not do what i require it to do. It is in a different form because in the form it is currently in, it sends a GET request to my java servlet which redirects it to a different page, than the first form does.

Answer (score 0):

My button id is NewSession which is defined after the form i.e. it is outside the form but I want it exactly at the side of form input type submit so I did this... it works!!!

```
#NewSession{
margin-top: -40px;
float: right;
margin-right: 510px;
}
```

You need to adjust the margin though which is a trial and error method...